# "Ken Burns effect" on hover background image?

Tags: javascript, css

I've got a parent div that has 30% width and 100% height with the background image set to cover.

What I want, is when I hover over over this div, I would like to create a "[**Ken Burns effect**](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/ken_burns_effect_css.htm)" on the background...

Currently this is my CSS code:

```
.col1 {
    margin-left : 20%;
    width : 26.66%;
    float : left;
    height : 100%;
    background : 
        linear-gradient(
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)
        ),
        url(images/rave.jpg);
    background-size : cover;
    background-position : left;
    opacity : 1;
    background-color : black;
}
```

Any ideas or if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: What is a "Ken Burns" effect?

Comment: https://www.kirupa.com/html5/ken_burns_effect_css.htm  It is a popular animation effect for images.. its pretty cool i'm just having a hard time applying that to my following code as its a background image :/ Dan

Comment: You could animate the `background-origin`

Comment: In fact, your link about the effect has a nice tutorial how to do it...

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you're looking for: http://codepen.io/hkfoster/pen/kechC

**CSS**

```
/* Better box-sizing */
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

/* 1rem = 10px */
html { font-size: 62.5%; }

/* Default body */
body { 
  margin: 0; 
  opacity: 0;
  font: 1.6rem/1.875 'Avenir Next', sans-serif;
}

/* Loaded body */
body.loaded {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s opacity;
}

/* Default banner */
.banner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40rem;
  padding: 0 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/* Default image container */
.banner .background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0) scale(1.25);
  background: black url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/150679257/hazy.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
  background-size: cover;
}

/* Loaded image container */
.loaded .banner .background {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: 6.5s transform;
}

/* Other stuff */
.banner h1 {
  color: #EEE;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 40rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 0 .3rem black;
}

main { 
  width: 90%;
  margin: 5rem auto;
}

main p { margin: 0 0 3rem 0; }
```

**JS**

```
// Trigger class name on load
window.onload = function() {
  document.body.className += ' loaded'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep `background-size: cover`, you won't be able to animate the background image's size. You could switch it to `background-size: 100%` in some cases to animate it: [see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xwj9vb7x/1/).

The effect is kind of jittery, though - I'd recommend wrapping `.col1` and animating the transform's scale instead, like in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xwj9vb7x/2/). You'll have to play around with the `background-position` property on the hover state to achieve the panning effect, but it looks much smoother this way.